# R Shiny: Issue with facet_wrap in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, facet-wrap

I am trying to create two side-by-side pie charts using `facet_wrap` in `ggplot` on R shiny. This is the code that I have currently:

```
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
if (input$type == "Pie Chart") {
  ggplot(shortlistpied(), aes_string(x = factor(1),  y = "Percentage", fill = input$y)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, position = position_fill()) + 
    coord_polar("y") + 
    facet_wrap( ~input$x) + 
    theme_void()
 } else NULL
})
```

This is what it produces: 
[image: Current Graph]

`input$x` in this case is Gender and `input$y` is Education.

As seen in the picture, the pie chart currently combines the results for both males and females into one chart. I am hoping to break up the two and below is an image showing what I hope to achieve (which I managed to do using a R markdown file):

[image: Desired Graog]

Can this be done in R shiny?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `input$x` is a characters string, so your are faceting on a constant which is why it's not working correctly. `facet_wrap(~get(input$x))` should work

Comment: Hi DiceboyT, thank you so much for your comment! It is working now (: